# How to cancel timeout inside of Javascript Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout, cancellation

I'm toying with promises in JavaScript and tried to promisify setTimeout function:

```
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('timeout done');
    }, ms);
  }); 
}

var myPromise=timeout(3000); 

myPromise.then(function(result) { 
  console.log(result); // timeout done
})
```

Fairly straightforward but I was wondering how would I go about canceling my timeout before the promise resolves. `timeout` returns `Promise` object hence I loose access to value that `setTimeout` returns and cannot cancel timeout via `clearTimeout`. What woud be the best way to do it?

BTW there is no real purpose for this, I just wonder how this would be approached. Also I plunked it here http://plnkr.co/edit/NXFjs1dXWVFNEOeCV1BA?p=preview

Comment: you can use decorators as well, more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61242606/1691423

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Edit 2021** all platforms have converged on AbortController as the cancellation primitive and there is some built in support for this.

#### In Node.js

```js
// import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises' // in ESM
const { setTimeout } = require('timers/promises');
const ac = new AbortController();

// cancellable timeout
(async () => {
  await setTimeout(1000, null, { signal: ac.signal });
})();

// abort the timeout, rejects with an ERR_ABORT
ac.abort();
```

#### In Browsers

You can polyfill this API and use the same as the example above:

```js
function delay(ms, value, { signal } = {}) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const listener = () => {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            reject(signal.reason);
        };
        signal?.throwIfAborted();
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            signal?.removeEventListener('abort', listener);
            resolve(value);
        }, ms);
        signal?.addEventListener('abort', listener);
    });
}
```

---

What you can do it that, you can return a canceller from your `timeout` function and invoke it when needed. This way you do not need to store the `timeoutid` globally (or on the outer scope) and also this can manage multiple calls to the function as well. Each instance of the object return by the function `timeout` will have its own canceler that can perform the cancellation.

```
function timeout(ms) {
  var timeout, promise;

  promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('timeout done');
    }, ms);
  }); 

  return {
           promise:promise, 
           cancel:function(){clearTimeout(timeout );} //return a canceller as well
         };
}

var timeOutObj =timeout(3000); 

timeOutObj.promise.then(function(result) { 
  console.log(result); // timeout done
});

//Cancel it.
timeOutObj.cancel();
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tydVRb?p=preview)**

Answer (score 22):

PSL's answer is right, however - there are a few caveats and I'd do it a bit differently.

- A timeout being cleared means the code will not run - so we should reject the promise.
- Returning two things isn't necessary in our case, we can monkey patch in JavaScript.

Here:

```
function timeout(ms, value) {
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        p._timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(value);
        }, ms);
        p.cancel = function(err) {
            reject(err || new Error("Timeout"));
            clearTimeout(p._timeout); // We actually don't need to do this since we
                                      // rejected - but it's well mannered to do so
        };
    });
    return p;
}
```

Which would let us do:

```
var p = timeout(1500)
p.then(function(){
     console.log("This will never log");
})

p.catch(function(){
     console.log("This will get logged so we can now handle timeouts!")
})
p.cancel(Error("Timed out"));
```

One might be interested in full blown cancellation and indeed some libraries support this directly as a feature of the library. In fact I'd dare say most do. However, this causes interference problems. Quoting KrisKowal from [here](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/18#issuecomment-51493764):

> My position on cancellation has evolved. I am now convinced that cancellation (**bg:** that propagates) is inherently impossible with the Promise abstraction because promises can multiple dependess and dependees can be introduced at any time. If any dependee cancels a promise, it would be able to interfere with future dependees. There are two ways to get around the problem. One is to introduce a separate cancellation "capability", perhaps passed as an argument. The other is to introduce a new abstraction, a perhaps thenable "Task", which in exchange for requiring that each task only have one observer (one then call, ever), can be canceled without fear of interference. Tasks would support a fork() method to create a new task, allowing another dependee to retain the task or postpone cancellation.

Comment: Although I can't find it documented anywhere, a Promise's "settler" function would appear to run in the same event turn as `var p = new Promise()`, therefore you can't have references to `p` inside the settler. The solution (at least the only one I can think of) is rather ugly but works - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9bnjevvu/).

Comment: Thus fixed, this is a better solution.

Comment: As an addendum to the quote, kriskowal has put up some more thoughts [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor/blob/master/cancelation.md)

Comment: @Benjamin-Gruenbaum has the better answer.  If you add members to the promise then you will not be able to cancel from a dependant promise (i.e., the .then() result); see [this article](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/03/cancelable-async-operations-promises-javascript/) for more information

Comment: It gives `TypeError: Cannot set property '_timeout' of undefined ` in timeout function.

Answer (score 3):

The above to answers by @Benjamin and @PSL work, but what if you need the cancelable timeout to be used by an outside source while being canceled internally?

For example, the interaction might look somewhat like this:

```
// externally usage of timeout 
async function() {
  await timeout() // timeout promise 
} 

// internal handling of timeout 
timeout.cancel()
```

I needed this kind of implementation myself, so here's what I came up with:

```
/**
 * Cancelable Timer hack.
 *
 *  @notes
 *    - Super() does not have `this` context so we have to create the timer
 *      via a factory function and use closures for the cancelation data.
 *    - Methods outside the consctutor do not persist with the extended
 *      promise object so we have to declare them via `this`.
 *  @constructor Timer
 */
function createTimer(duration) {
  let timerId, endTimer
  class Timer extends Promise {
    constructor(duration) {
      // Promise Construction
      super(resolve => {
        endTimer = resolve
        timerId = setTimeout(endTimer, duration)
      })
      // Timer Cancelation
      this.isCanceled = false
      this.cancel = function() {
        endTimer()
        clearTimeout(timerId)
        this.isCanceled = true
      }
    }
  }
  return new Timer(duration)
}
```

Now you can use the timer like this:

```
let timeout = createTimer(100)
```

And have the promise canceled somewhere else:

```
 if (typeof promise !== 'undefined' && typeof promise.cancel === 'function') {
  timeout.cancel() 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer in TypeScript:

```
  private sleep(ms) {
    let timerId, endTimer;
    class TimedPromise extends Promise<any> {
      isCanceled: boolean = false;
      cancel = () => {
        endTimer();
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        this.isCanceled = true;
      };
      constructor(fn) {
        super(fn);
      }
    }
    return new TimedPromise(resolve => {
      endTimer = resolve;
      timerId = setTimeout(endTimer, ms);
    });
  }
```

Usage:

```
const wait = sleep(10*1000);
setTimeout(() => { wait.cancel() },5 * 1000);
await wait;
```