# Check if push is successful - angularfire2

Tags: error-handling, ionic2, angularfire2

currently i develop an Ionic2 application which commuicates with a Firebase database. While updating a node sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.
So i tired to handle the error with the following code:

```
this.db.list("/Events/" + this.eventID+ "/teilnehmer").push(this.userID)
        .then(resolve => {
          console.log('success');
        }, reject => {
          console.log('error');
        })
        .catch(reject => {
          console.log('catch');
        });
```

But even if i disconnect my internet connection there is no error thrown.
Does someone of you know how i could handle an error if the push was not successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same situation that push does not return promises sometime, so i raised issue on github [FirebaseListObservable push() takes too long to add](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/896) but unfortunately it was not resolved, I contacted firebase support through email, the support team reviewed my issue and checked the code i sent, and replied there is nothing to do in the code , and advised me to ***clear the phone's storage cache***, i did the same and **issue got resolved,**

here is the mail from firebase support

> Hi xxxx,
>
> I suggest that you try clearing your phone's cache before proceeding
>   again, its memory might be too high. To do this, go to: Settings ->
>   Storage -> Cached Data. Select it then then choose ok (for clearing
>   the cache).   Also please check this the same issue raised on Github
>   and answered by one of our engineers.
>
> If the issue persists after trying the proposed suggestions, please
>   get back to me with a minimal and runnable code that we can use to
>   simulate this, possibly a plunkr or jsfiddle code,  or a from the
>   scratch code that can demonstrate the issue.
>
> Regards, xxxx

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to handle this you could consider setting a timeout because  the Promise will just stay in 'pending' if Firebase doesn't return anything and resolve, reject / catch will never be triggered.

You could do this for example with Promise.race(): [Example Promise timeout with Promise.race()](https://www.promisejs.org/patterns/) also check this thread: [More Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461271/nodejs-timeout-a-promise-if-failed-to-complete-in-time)