# Externally return a value from a promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I wrote a function `calc` that can finish normally or run forever based on user input and I can't control that. I want to write a function `limited_calc` that wraps around it to provide a time limit and stops running the function once the time is up. I've got the time limit working with something like this:

```
function limited_calc(max_time, input) {
    var timed = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, max_time, "Time limit reached");
        resolve(calc(input));
    }
    return ???
}

function calc(input) {
    // (do the stuff)
}
```

Using `.then()` with `console.log()` shows the correct output, but `return`ing in `.then()` gives a promise as it's supposed to, but *not* the value itself. How can I return the result from the line with `return ???`? I know setting an outer variable and then another, longer timeout works, but seems unsafe. How do I do this the intended way?

Resource I used: the class defined in the accepted answer [NodeJS Timeout a Promise if failed to complete in time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461271/nodejs-timeout-a-promise-if-failed-to-complete-in-time) .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) - I hope it answers your question.

Comment: When you say it "runs forever", do you mean the page freezes? If yes, you cannot have a "max execution time" and need to rework your function to make it error prone.

Comment: "*stops running the function*" - how can it do that?

Comment: I `calc` actually asynchronous? If yes, it should take a callback or better return a promise, if no, then you cannot give it a time limit with `setTimeout` and your promise code won't work like that.

Comment: "*How can I return the result from the line with return?*" - you can't, it's asynchronous. Just return the `timed` promise! To access the value, you have to use `then` as it's supposed to.

Comment: I used the implementation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461271/nodejs-timeout-a-promise-if-failed-to-complete-in-time and if `calc()` contained a `while(1) {}` it `reject`ed with "Time limit reached" as I want, is there a way to return that, or the `result`?

Comment: @BenjaminPhilippe I doubt it works if your code contains `while (1)`. Can you please post your complete implementation?

Comment: @Bergi What worked was using `if((new Date).getTime() - start_time)` every time the loop went around, thanks for your time!