# How to add a timeout in a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, timeout

I have read many different ways of adding timeouts within a promise, but most, if not all, seem to utilise the `setTimeout()` method. By definition:

```
The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.
```

What I am looking for is a way to say:

```
"If the function executed inside the promise (that will either resolve or
reject the promise), does not complete within a specified x number of
milliseconds, automatically reject or raise an exception."
```

If this is the same as the defined above (using the `setTimeout()` method), an explanation would be highly appreciated!

Comment: See also [Timeout in async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37120240/1048572) and [Timeout a Promise if failed to complete in time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32461271/1048572)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can wrap `setTimeout` in a Promise and create a little "wait"-function which you can then use with [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

```
function wait(ms) {
   return new Promise((_, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timeout succeeded')), ms);
   });
}

try {
  const result = await Promise.race([wait(1000), yourAsyncFunction()]);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

With this code `Promise.race` will reject if `yourAsyncFunction` takes longer than 1000 `ms` to resolve/reject, otherwise `result` will yield the resolved value from `yourAsyncFunction`.

Comment: If I only have one Promise function, would something like:
`
function() {
  return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => { return rej(new Error("Timed out!")); });
    return asyncFunction(){}
      .then((data) => { return res(data); })
      .catch((err) => { return rej(err); });
`

Comment: Sorry, not fully sure how to properly comment a code block in the comment section of StackOverflow..

Comment: You mean how you can use my code in a function?

Comment: Along those lines yes. To my understanding, your code creates a separate promise to my function and then if my function does not complete faster than the promise you created, the rejection is executed first?

Comment: Yes, I think overall this can be used as a general guideline and I might tweak it just a bit to suit my needs. Thank you!