# How to await a list of promises excluding ones that reject

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

I currently have this working JS code:

```
async (list) => {
        var peers = await Promise.allSettled(list);
        peers = peers.filter(peer => peer.status === "fulfilled");
        return Promise.all(peers);
    }
```

However, it plays havoc with Typescript's type system. What's the recommended way to do this?

Comment: `Promise.allSettled` fulfills when all promises settle. If you're concerned about a single promise not settling in a timely fashion, you can put a timer on it. TJ Crowder shows an example here [NodeJS Timeout a Promise if failed to complete in time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32461436/4797603)

Comment: What do you mean by "*it plays havoc with Typescript's type system.*"? Your function has no type annotations so it's not clear what you expect. If you're getting a type error, please post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit `Promise.all()` and just return the [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled#return_value) from the fulfilled promises

```ts
const fulfill = async <T,>(list: Promise<T>[]): Promise<T[]> => {
  // Wait for all promises to complete then filter for "fulfilled"
  const fulfilled = (await Promise.allSettled(list)).filter(
    ({ status }) => status === "fulfilled"
  ) as PromiseFulfilledResult<T>[]; // this cast lets you access `.value`

  // Map out the `.value` properties
  return fulfilled.map(({ value }) => value);
};
```

There's no need for `Promise.all()` because your `async` function already returns a promise which you're resolving with an array produced by `Promise.allSettled()`.

Using this will produce an array of successfully resolved values

```ts
const list: Promise<number>[] = [
  Promise.resolve(1),
  Promise.resolve(2),
  Promise.reject(3),
  Promise.resolve(5),
];

console.log(await fulfill(list)); // [1, 2, 5]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVwDZwJZKTAvDAhhATzGBgB4AVAGgD4AKJVaALhgAUAnEAW0YFMLqAbQC6AShYdufCiOrY5AbwBQMGAHo1MAOq5UsOCHZ4MMAA6ceEXhBhQQMUF1NJeUXrYAWvMPHRujBkYARIgo6C4AJkEqDuDQ8MhoGLwR2DC0uADuurCSlrwAdLgYAMquUJH0jFCiogVJ-rQxqrQKMNC4UAg2AL6i8u1Qnd3YWDghieEp0ar9+GwWfABik8kRAErWyFACIgDc6ppQHowO+LAuUDYEIAh4wMDWNgAGBQBuxQi8z0oxGjAAWVwphgt1gx3crw+SC+zzMnFMvHYUFQ1hi7FcCHYPlCSUiBS4wNorRg0K+MD6AzJvFEeyUPTpSlAkAu1QkiyspDACC4ACMkUJhGlBDE8nwChiICAkG9eLQAIyiSiijmFSXS2W0ABMSpVUisEt4ACteMAoLQAMy61Rig3qmVygAsuuEjNx4Sq0DqELAtGZUpcBSQIAA5qIgA)

Comment: This doesn't change the result from the OP's code as calling `Promise.all(peers)` just returns `peers` anyway.  I agree that `Promise.all()` was not needed, but this doesn't fix/change the result.

Comment: @jfriend00 OP is returning an array of `PromiseSettledResult`. I assumed from their comment _"plays havoc with Typescript's type system"_ that they'd rather the resolved values returned instead