# How can I do I cancel javascript await sleep?

Tags: javascript

The most common implementation of a sleep function in javascript is returning a Promise after setTimeout resolves:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}
```

I have for loop with await sleep to keep it from executing too fast, such as not requesting xhr too fast. I also have a isBreak flag elsewhere to tell me when to stop the for loop. However, the issue I have is that when I break the for loop, the previous await sleep has already executed and is holding up the for loop. Is there a better way of breaking the for loop and also terminating the await sleep instantaneously?

```
const items = [];

let isBreak = false; // Somewhere else in the application

for (const item of items) {
  if (isBreak) break;

  // Do something, like xhr request
  await sleep(15000); // 15 seconds sleep

  if (isBreak) break;
}
```

Is there a way for me to signal for early

Comment: If you really need the Promise implementation, FZs' answer is excellent.

Comment: However, have you considered just using a `setInterval` and cancelling the interval ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JS, when an `await` operation starts, it can no longer be interrupted; it will wait until its operand promise is settled.

So, you have to make the promise you're `await`ing cancelable in some way.

Unfortunately, your code can't get notified about a variable reassignment (when you set `isBreak` to `true`), and polling it would be inefficient.

Instead of a flag, you could use an `AbortSignal` (which was invented for this purpose), and make your `sleep` accept one:

```
function sleep(ms, signal) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    signal.throwIfAborted();

    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
      signal.removeEventListener('abort', abort);
    }, ms);

    const abort = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      reject(signal.reason);
    }

    signal.addEventListener('abort', abort);
  });
}
```

Then, you use it like this:

```js
const items = [];

const isBreak = new AbortController(); // Somewhere else in the application, call `isBreak.abort()`

try {
  for (const item of items) {
    // Do something, like xhr request
    await sleep(15000, isBreak.signal); // 15 seconds sleep
  }
} catch (e) {
  if (e.name === 'TimeoutError') {
    // Handle a cancellation
    console.log('Cancelled');
  } else {
    // Not a cancellation, rethrow it
    throw e;
  }
}
```

An `AbortSignal` works well with `fetch` as well, in case you have to cancel that too.

Comment: I completely forgot about adding event signals. This should work. Thanks.

Comment: TypeScript version with unit tests: https://gist.github.com/tkrotoff/c6dd1cabf5570906724097c6e3f65a12

Answer (score -1):

An answer i found in a blog in the past that i adjusted. It is similiar to FZs answer. Same usage, too. Just to give an alternative.

relevant too: [How to cancel timeout inside of Javascript Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345701/how-to-cancel-timeout-inside-of-javascript-promise)

```js
function sleep(ms, abortSignal) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    signal.addEventListener("abort", abort);
    if(abortSignal.aborted){
      abort();
    }
    const timeout = setTimeout(end, ms);

    function abort() {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      abortSignal.removeEventListener("abort", abort);
      reject(new Error("sleep aborted"));
    }

    function end() {
      abortSignal.removeEventListener("abort", abort);
      resolve();
    }
  });
}
```